# Tooltips undefined in ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following tooltip example it works fine in chrome and firefox - but in ie7 and ie8 it keeps coming back as undefined and flickers when you hoverover the question mark

http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/nHDf4/4/

not sure what has gone wrong for IE.

Comment: Ok for me on IE 7.0.6001

Comment: A quick suggestion: You should never assume that you'll get exactly matching mouseover/mouseout events, e.g. mouseover could be called multiple time bevore mouseout is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use multiple bind method instead of pure events;

your problem appears; when mouse comes to object twice or more but when bind method used, there will be no undefined return on internet explorer.

check this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nHDf4/12/